# FTPError: 550 Access is denied in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ftp, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure Release Pipeline (classic) to upload build files to FTP (not ftps) Server.
It can able to transfer all files successfully, but only one file showing below error,

[image]

That only file is not able to overwrite.

Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the file that failed to be overwritten is read-only. I can reproduce the same error if file is read-only on my ftp server. See [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/811883/configure-filezilla-ftp-server-to-allow-uploads).

Above error can also be caused by the file being used by another process and being locked. See [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1169427.aspx).

You can also check if the [Agent Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#account) has the modify permission to this file. See [here](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=5559).

Comment: Just for mention this: My problem was uploading WP theme and it solved by changing active theme, because it was using by another process. thanks @Levi Lu-MSFT